# display radio button using html script

Tags: android

> I need to display this html script in Edit Text

```
String s = "<html><body>" +"<p>"+" <input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'> Male<Br>" +"<input type='radio'name='gender'value='female'> Female<Br>" +"<input type='radio' name='gender' value='other'> Other" +"</p>" +"</body></html>";
```

> but the values only are appear but radio button itself not appear Please , any Suggestion to display radio buttons with its values .

Comment: use layout xml where you can add radio buttons and display as your activity or fragment view instead of use html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not support all the tags.

Please refer developer link : [CLICK HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)

For the list of tags that are supports in android please visit this link: [CLICK HERE](https://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

Comment: Ok " chirag patel " , but if i need to display radio button what is the solution ?!

Comment: @user7779151, Can you please share your scenario like why you need to display radio button inside edit text instend of place outside of edit text ? So i can help you easily.

Comment: I need to display a template html in my app in Edit text from Server and return changes makes in these radio buttons to server again

Comment: You can not load all the tags like web. Better you can load web URL in web view for particular template. Or you can design template in android. For my personal opinion if you no need to manipulate filled data of template just load web URL in web view. And if you want values than you have to design.

Comment: Thanks chirag patel can make an example here

Comment: @user7779151 :For what you want example ? For calling URL in web view or design template.

Comment: design template